# Create network location wix installer

Tags: c#, wix

The requirement is to sync a folder between two or more windows servers. The folder can be uploaded to any of the servers and once it is uploaded there will be a download request to any of the servers. So there can be situations where the server receives the download request doesn't have the folder uploaded. I know there is DFS(distributed file system) or Robocopy to sync contents but that will have a delay, so during syncing the download request may hit the server.
In wix We can create a folder and share it but that will be a shared folder in the server. I want to create a location which is available for all the servers. Im trying to accomplish this from wix. is it possible ?
Any thoughts ?

Comment: I suspect you have confused the wix tag (for Windows Installer Xml development creating MSI files) with the wix product for web servers.

Comment: @PhilDW i meant the Windows Installer Xml development creating MSI files. not the wix.com.